# Cannot encode decode in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using django 2.2 and python 3.6.
I have a django template html file.

> Exception Type:   UnicodeDecodeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1407: invalid continuation byte
>
> The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: "">Se�in

If the string was in views.py i was able to encode decode it. But this string is manually put in html template file. If i delete this character it works fine.
How can i encode decode this string in the template?

My editor is notepad++ and setting is:

[image]

Comment: Check if your editor is set to right encoding.

Comment: I checked notepad++ encoding setting. It is utf-8.

Comment: You were right Klaus my friend. I downloaded file to my local and checked it. It was ANSI. I converted file to UTF-8 file. Now it works. You can add the answer. I was editor problem.